# Proving that a set has no largest member

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof

Here's the question in mind.

Let $$A = \left\{r : r \quad \text{is a rational number and} \quad r^2 < 2\right\}$$Prove that $A$ has no largest number.

(Hint: if $r^2 < 2$, and $r > 0$, choose a rational number $δ$ such that $0< δ < 1$ and $δ < (2-r^2)/(2r+1)$ show that $(r + δ)^2< 2$)

I was wondering if I could answer this question by assuming that $r$, which is an element of $A$, is the largest element. Can I then construct a new element $p$, where $p = r+δ$ and $p^2 < 2$. If that is the case, how would I go about proving that $p^2 $is in fact less than $2$? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about supremums?

Comment: Or least upper bounds?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: Shouldn't have to know about suprema.  The purpose of this exercise is to introduce the Q does *not* have suprema property.

Comment: Assuming $\delta < 1$ you have $$p^2=(r+ \delta)^2 = r^2 + 2 \delta r + \delta^2 < r^2 + 2 \delta r + \delta = r^2 + \delta (2r+1)< r^2 + (2-r^2) = 2$$

Comment: You *can* use knowing that no rational number squared equals 2, and $x^2$ is increasing, and the rationals are dense in the reals which have the least upper bound property to conclude that the set has no maximum, but I think that would be missing the point of this exercise, whose point is simply to introduce those very concepts  to the student via direct examples.

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint in the given question....

Consider a rational number $r$ such that $r^2\lt 2$. Now, consider $p=(r+\delta)$ where $\delta$ is a positive real less than $1$ satisfying $\delta\lt\dfrac{2-r^2}{2r+1}$. So, obviously we have $p\gt r$. Then, we have,

$$\delta\lt\frac{2-r^2}{2r+1}\implies r^2+2r\delta\lt 2-\delta\implies (r+\delta)^2\lt 2-\delta+\delta^2\tag1$$

Since $0\lt\delta\lt 1$, we have $\delta^2\lt\delta\implies -\delta+\delta^2\lt 0\implies 2-\delta+\delta^2\lt 2\tag2$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get,

$$(r+\delta)^2\lt 2\implies p^2\lt 2$$

Hence, the set $\{r\in\Bbb Q\colon r^2\lt 2\}$ has no maximum.